# Who's the girl Panther Lily's with in the wedding dress pose off?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the Fairy Tail anime during the Grand Magic Games when Jenny fights Mirajane they decide to do a pose off and girls from all the guilds start posing. When they start posing in wedding dresses panther lily is with some tiny girl who is that? this is in episode 163 of the anime

Answer (score 2):

That is the daughter of Bisca and Alzack, **[Asuka Conell](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Asuka_Connell)**.

> One year after the disappearance of the Team Tenrou, Fairy Tail Mages Alzack Connell and Bisca Mulan married each other and their relationship blossomed, eventually resulting in the birth of Asuka ("A" came from Alzack and "-suka" from Bisuka, the Romaji version of her mother's name).

I couldn't find the image, but I am sure it was Asuka in a wedding dress.

Comment: That makes sense this is a link to the picture if you were interested http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/fairytail/images/7/70/Levy_as_a_bride_and_Gajeel_as_a_groom.png/revision/latest?cb=20130105143220